# Quicker way to solve 10! congruent to x (mod 11)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am new to modular arithmetic and solving congruences and the way I went about this was to write out $10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot2$, then multiply numbers until I get a number greater than $11$, replace it with a smaller number in its congruence class and repeat.  Is there a quicker way to go about this?  The next question I must solve is $100!\equiv x \pmod {101}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) states that for any prime number $n$, you get $$(n-1)! \equiv -1 (mod\ n).$$

$10!$ makes $n = 11$, which is prime, so $10! \equiv -1 (mod\ 11) \equiv 10 (mod\ 11)$

Likewise, $100!$ makes $n = 101$, which is prime, so $100! \equiv -1 (mod\ 101) \equiv 100 (mod\ 101)$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem

Comment: Very good way of solving the problem. On an aside Wilson's theorem is an "if and only if" statement which implies that for any $n$ such that the above is true, then $n$ is prime.

Comment: What about the case when n is not prime?

Comment: say 101! (mod 102)

Comment: Ooh, can't really help you there, buddy. It's not as nice for non-prime numbers. Umm... just plug it into Wolfram Alpha? :P

Comment: no calculators allowed in this class.

Comment: Aww man. Well I'd say your best hope then is to pray to whichever higher being you believe in (if you do) that your teacher isn't evil enough to ask something like that.

Comment: @Juan If $n$ is composite and $n>4$, then $(n-1)! \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

We can pair numbers, since $$10 \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$$ $$9 \equiv -2 \pmod{11}$$

and so on. So your product is the same as

$$(-1) (-2 \cdot 2)(-3 \cdot 3)(-4 \cdot 4)(-5 \cdot 5) \pmod{11}$$

or after dealing with signs,

$$-2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 4^2 \cdot 5^2 \pmod{11}$$

Now $2^2 \equiv 4$, $3^2 \equiv -2$, $4^2 \equiv 5$ and $5^2 \equiv 3$, so this can be written as

$$-(4)(-2)(5)(3) \pmod{11}$$

or $$8 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \pmod{11}$$

Now $40 \equiv 7$ and $21 \equiv -1$ leads to

$$\boxed{-1 \pmod{11}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know Wilson's theorem you might stumble upon its idea tackling this problem using elementary facts and being lazy.

The non-zero elements in $\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /11\mathbb {Z}$ form a group and each element has a unique inverse. OK, listing the elements,

$\tag 1 {\overline {1}},{\overline {2}},{\overline {3}},{\overline {4}},{\overline {5}},{\overline {6}},{\overline {7}},{\overline {8}},{\overline {9}},{\overline {10}}$

and you get a little excited since $10!$ modulo $11$ boils down to multiplying them all together.

So an easy first step for the lazy mathematician is to replace the list with

$\tag 2 {\overline {2}},{\overline {3}},{\overline {4}},{\overline {5}},{\overline {6}},{\overline {7}},{\overline {8}},{\overline {9}},{\overline {-1}}$

Looking for pairs of elements, each the multiplicative inverse of the other, you wonder if you can multiply two representative numbers  together and get $12$. Yup, $2 \times 6 = 12$ and $3 \times 4 = 12$. Great, now looking at

$\tag 3 {\overline {5}},{\overline {7}},{\overline {8}},{\overline {9}},{\overline {-1}}$

How about 'multiplying out' to $23 = 12 + 11$. Nope.

How about 'multiplying out' to $34 = 23 + 11$. Nope.

How about 'multiplying out' to $45 = 34 + 11$. Yup, $5 \times 9 = 45$. New list

$\tag 4 {\overline {7}},{\overline {8}},{\overline {-1}}$

How about 'multiplying out' to $56 = 45 + 11$. Yup, $7 \times 8 = 56$.

ANS: $10! \equiv -1 \pmod{11}$

---

Note: If $p$ is a prime the solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ are $x \in \{1,-1\}$. So with $p \ge 5$ the elements in the non-empty set

$\quad \displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /p\mathbb {Z} \setminus \{{\overline {0}},{\overline {1}}, {\overline {-1}}\}$

can be always be '$a\text{-}b$ paired off' with

$\quad \displaystyle ab \equiv 1 (\text{mod } p) \land a \ne b$